# Cannot resolve method error when try passing a overloaded method as argument

Tags: java, lambda

I try to pass Integer::parseInt as an argument to another function.

But since Integer::parseInt can take either (String) or (String, int) as input, the method can't be resolved.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        h.withinRange(Integer::parseInt);
    }

    public void withinRange(Function<Integer, String> function) {
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether this is doable or not.

Comment: You have the type parameters the wrong way around, the second one is the return type.

Comment: @JornVernee, thank you. I have a follow up quetion. Following your advice, I tried Function<String, Integer> and Function<String, Object> and they all worked. But when I tried Function<Object, Object> it can't resolve again, I put 'Object' for input type to make it more general and String is subtype of Object, not ure why it complain there..

Comment: You can't call `Integer.parseInt` with an `Object` either, you _need_ a `String`. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare it either as `public void withinRange(Function< String,Integer> function)` or as `public void withinRange(ToIntFunction< String> function)` (whatever seems more appropriate).